# Drag canvas without content restriction

Tags: javascript, canvas, gojs

In a simple GoJS diagram, dragging the canvas allows us to move the entire graph. By default, you can only drag the canvas until the graph collides with the sides, so that the graph will never leave the canvas window.

How do I change the code to remove that restriction (ie, I can drag the canvas and the graph does not collide with the sides and exit the canvas window)?

Comment: You are required to post an example of your code here. Third party links go dead helping no one and make your question useless: [mcve]

Comment: This question did not require any code.  Insisting on providing it makes the question harder to understand due to the extraneous verbiage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy answer is to set https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#scrollMode to `go.Diagram.InfiniteScroll`.

```
$(go.Diagram, ..., {
    scrollMode: go.Diagram.InfiniteScroll,
    ...
  })
```

Read more at https://gojs.net/latest/intro/viewport.html.  Play at https://gojs.net/latest/samples/scrollModes.html.